# Secondary axis not displaying on chart.js, line graph

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have created a line chart using chart.js, and I would like the second y-axis (MinutesofUsage) to be displayed on the right side of the graph (secondary axis).

This is the section of the code that displays the graph.

```
<script>
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
    var callTypes = <?php echo json_encode(array_unique(array_column($data, "callType"))); ?>;

    // Function to create a chart with dynamic Y-axis scales
    function createChartWithYAxis(index) {
        if (index < callTypes.length) {
            var callType = callTypes[index];
            var chartContainer = document.createElement('div');
            chartContainer.className = 'chart-container';

            // Add the chart name
            var chartTitle = document.createElement('div');
            chartTitle.innerText = 'Chart: ' + callType;
            chartContainer.appendChild(chartTitle);

            var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
            ctx.canvas.id = callType + 'Chart';

            ctx.canvas.style.display = 'block';
            chartContainer.appendChild(ctx.canvas);

            document.body.appendChild(chartContainer);

            var filteredData = data.filter(function (item) {
                return item.callType === callType;
            });

            var dates = filteredData.map(function (item) {
                return item.date;
            });
            var revenues = filteredData.map(function (item) {
                return item.revenue;
            });
            var minutesUsage = filteredData.map(function (item) {
                return item.minutesUsage;
            });

            new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: dates,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: 'Minutes Usage',
                            data: minutesUsage,
                            borderColor: 'green',
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            fill: false,
                            yAxisID: 'minutes-axis'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Total Revenue',
                            data: revenues,
                            borderColor: 'blue',
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            fill: false,
                            yAxisID: 'revenue-axis'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    layout: {
                        padding: {
                            left: 5,
                            right: 5
                        }
                    },
                    scales: {
                        x: [{
                            type: 'time',
                            time: {
                                unit: 'day'
                            },
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Date'
                            }
                        }],
                        y: [
                            {
                                id: 'revenue-axis',
                                position: 'left', //position of the y-axis(revenue-axis)
                                title: {
                                    display: true,
                                    text: 'Total Revenue',
                                    fontColor: 'blue' // Set the color for the revenue y-axis label
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                    fontColor: 'blue' // Set the color for the revenue y-axis ticks
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                id: 'minutes-axis',
                                position: 'right', //position of the y-axis(minutesofusage-axis)
                                title: {
                                    display: true,
                                    text: 'Minutes Usage',
                                    fontColor: 'green' // Set the color for the minutes y-axis label
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                    fontColor: 'green' // Set the color for the minutes y-axis ticks
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        datalabels: {
                            display: 'auto',
                            color: 'black',
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            // Smooth scroll to the newly created chart
            chartContainer.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
        } else {
            clearInterval(chartInterval); // Stop the slideshow
        }
    }

    var currentIndex = 0;
    var chartInterval = setInterval(function() {
        createChartWithYAxis(currentIndex);
        currentIndex++;
    }, 5000); // Delay between chart displays (in milliseconds)
</script>
```

I tried changing the position attribute to right, and there has been no change to the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Chart.js you are using, the `chart.options.scales.x` and `chart.options.scales.y` shouldn't be arrays. You should have one object per axis in `chart.options.scales`, such as:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');


var cfg = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'A',
      data: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
      yAxisID: 'revenueAxis'
  },{
      label: 'B',
      data: [5,10,15,30,25,20,35,50,45,40,45],
      yAxisID: 'minutesAxis'
  }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        title: {
          text: 'Date',
          display: true
        }
      },
      revenueAxis: {
        type: 'linear',
        title: {
          text: 'Total Revenue',
          display: true
        },
        position: 'left'
      },
      minutesAxis: {
        type: 'linear',
        position:'right',
        title: {
          text: 'Minutes Axis',
          display: true
        },
      }
    }
  },
}

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, cfg);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.0/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```